# ¿Por qué sale este error: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/TestLap/TC2/xxx.php on line 66?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Necesito encontrar la causa que me está generando este error a la hora de llenar el formulario, dado que no me había pasado y ahora está pasando.

Uso el código php para insertar los datos introducidos en el formulario que tengo diseñado para un servicio de transportes:

```
    <?php
    $hostname_TC2P = "localhost";
    $database_TC2P = "klmd3108g";
    $username_TC2P = "root";
    $password_TC2P = "Test20";
    $TC2P = mysqli_connect($hostname_TC2P, $username_TC2P, $password_TC2P, 
    $database_TC2P) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

    mysqli_set_charset($TC2P, 'utf8');


    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }
    
      global $TC2P;
      $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($TC2P,$theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($TC2P,$theValue);
    
      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO db_servicios (id_in, fecha_servicio, servicio_num, n_destino, n_vuelo, db_terminal, hora_llegada, hora_pickup, num_pax, nom_usuario, nombre_pax, nom_hotel, nom_cuenta, forma_pago, tipo_servicio1, nombre_proveedor, n_servicio, num_folio, comentarios_1, comentarios_2, comentarios_3, tipo_transporte, estatus_serv) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id_in'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['fecha_servicio'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['servicio_num'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['n_destino'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['n_vuelo'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['db_terminal'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hora_llegada'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hora_pickup'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['num_pax'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nom_usuario'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nombre_pax'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nom_hotel'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nom_cuenta'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['forma_pago'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tipo_servicio1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nombre_proveedor'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['n_servicio'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['num_folio'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios_1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios_2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios_3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tipo_transporte'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['estatus_serv'], "text"));

     $Result1 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error());

     $insertGoTo = "main.php";
     if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
     $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
     $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
     }
     header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
     }

     $query_InsertarServicios72 = "SELECT * FROM db_servicios";
     $InsertarServicios72 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_InsertarServicios72) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_InsertarServicios72 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($InsertarServicios72);
     $totalRows_InsertarServicios72 = mysqli_num_rows($InsertarServicios72);

     $query_TCuentas11 = "SELECT * FROM db_cuentas";
     $TCuentas11 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TCuentas11) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TCuentas11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TCuentas11);
     $totalRows_TCuentas11 = mysqli_num_rows($TCuentas11);

     $query_THoteles21 = "SELECT * FROM db_hoteles";
     $THoteles21 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_THoteles21) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_THoteles21 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($THoteles21);
     $totalRows_THoteles21 = mysqli_num_rows($THoteles21);

     $query_TRazonSocial31 = "SELECT * FROM db_razonsocial";
     $TRazonSocial31 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TRazonSocial31) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TRazonSocial31 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TRazonSocial31);
     $totalRows_TRazonSocial31 = mysqli_num_rows($TRazonSocial31);

     $query_TServiciosN41 = "SELECT * FROM db_servicios_2";
     $TServiciosN41 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TServiciosN41) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TServiciosN41 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TServiciosN41);
     $totalRows_TServiciosN41 = mysqli_num_rows($TServiciosN41);

     $query_TServiciosCom51 = "SELECT * FROM db_servicios_3";
     $TServiciosCom51 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TServiciosCom51) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TServiciosCom51 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TServiciosCom51);
     $totalRows_TServiciosCom51 = mysqli_num_rows($TServiciosCom51);

     $query_TTerminales61 = "SELECT * FROM db_terminales";
     $TTerminales61 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TTerminales61) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TTerminales61 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TTerminales61);
     $totalRows_TTerminales61 = mysqli_num_rows($TTerminales61);

     $query_TServicio71 = "SELECT * FROM db_tipodeservicio";
     $TServicio71 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TServicio71) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TServicio71 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TServicio71);
     $totalRows_TServicio71 = mysqli_num_rows($TServicio71);

     $query_TTransporte81 = "SELECT * FROM db_tipodetransporte";
     $TTransporte81 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TTransporte81) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TTransporte81 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TTransporte81);
     $totalRows_TTransporte81 = mysqli_num_rows($TTransporte81);

     $query_TMiembros91 = "SELECT usuario FROM db_usuarios";
     $TMiembros91 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TMiembros91) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TMiembros91 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TMiembros91);
     $totalRows_TMiembros91 = mysqli_num_rows($TMiembros91);

     $query_TStatusServicios101 = "SELECT * FROM estatus_servicio";
     $TStatusServicios101 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TStatusServicios101) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TStatusServicios101 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TStatusServicios101);
     $totalRows_TStatusServicios101 = mysqli_num_rows($TStatusServicios101);

     $query_TPagos111 = "SELECT * FROM formas_pago";
     $TPagos111 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TPagos111) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TPagos111 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TPagos111);
     $totalRows_TPagos111 = mysqli_num_rows($TPagos111);

     $query_TRfcRazonSocial121 = "SELECT * FROM rfc_razonsocial";
     $TRfcRazonSocial121 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $query_TRfcRazonSocial121) or die(mysqli_error());
     $row_TRfcRazonSocial121 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TRfcRazonSocial121);
     $totalRows_TRfcRazonSocial121 = mysqli_num_rows($TRfcRazonSocial121);
     ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <table>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Fecha <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="fecha_servicio" value="" size="32" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">ID <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="ID de 6 dígitos" pattern=".{6,}" maxlength="6" type="text" name="servicio_num" value="" size="32" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Destino <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="RMY o CUN" pattern=".{3,}" maxlength="3" type="text" name="n_destino" value="" size="32" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">No. de vuelo <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Número de vuelo de la aerolínea proporcionada por el cliente." maxlength="8" type="text" name="n_vuelo" value="" size="32" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Terminal <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="db_terminal" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TTerminales61['num_terminal']?>" ><?php echo $row_TTerminales61['num_terminal']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TTerminales61 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TTerminales61));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Hora de llegada <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="time" name="hora_llegada" value="" size="32" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Hora de salida <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="time" name="hora_pickup" value="" size="32" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">No. de pasajeros <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Número de pasajeros" maxlength="5" type="text" name="num_pax" value="" size="32" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Usuario <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="nom_usuario" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TMiembros91['usuario']?>" ><?php echo $row_TMiembros91['usuario']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TMiembros91 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TMiembros91));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Cliente <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre (s) de (los) cliente (s)." name="nombre_pax" cols="32" required></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Hotel <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="nom_hotel" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_THoteles21['nombre_hotel']?>" ><?php echo $row_THoteles21['nombre_hotel']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_THoteles21 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($THoteles21));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Cuenta <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="nom_cuenta" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TCuentas11['nombre_cuenta']?>" ><?php echo $row_TCuentas11['nombre_cuenta']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TCuentas11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TCuentas11));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Forma de pago <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="forma_pago" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TPagos111['formas_pago']?>" ><?php echo $row_TPagos111['formas_pago']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TPagos111 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TPagos111));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Tipo de servicio <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="tipo_servicio1" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TServicio71['n_tservicio']?>" ><?php echo $row_TServicio71['n_tservicio']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TServicio71 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TServicio71));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Proveedor (Driver) <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del driver o proveedor." type="text" name="nombre_proveedor" value="" size="32" required/> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Servicio <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="n_servicio" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TServiciosN41['n_servicio2']?>" ><?php echo $row_TServiciosN41['n_servicio2']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TServiciosN41 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TServiciosN41));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td>No. de folio (sólo si aplica):</td>
      <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="No. de folio sólo si aplica" type="text" name="num_folio" value="" size="32"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td>Comentarios principales <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba aquí los comentarios principales." name="comentarios_1" cols="32" rows="5" required></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td>Comentarios adicionales:</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba aquí los comentarios adicionales o para el cliente." name="comentarios_2" cols="32" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td>Observaciones o sugerencias adicionales:</td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba aquí las observaciones o sugerencias agregadas." name="comentarios_3" cols="32" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Tipo de transporte <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="tipo_transporte" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TTransporte81['n_transporte']?>" ><?php echo $row_TTransporte81['n_transporte']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TTransporte81 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TTransporte81));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap">Estatus del Servicio <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
      <td><select class="form-control" name="estatus_serv" required>
        <?php 
    do {  
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_TStatusServicios101['estatus_servicio']?>" ><?php echo $row_TStatusServicios101['estatus_servicio']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_TStatusServicios101 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TStatusServicios101));
    ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card mb-4">
    <div class="card-body">
    <table>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" >&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Insertar registro" class="btn-danger btn" align="center"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="id_in" value="" />
   <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
   </form>
```

Todo bien hasta ahora. El detalle está en que por alguna razón extraña sale este error:

```
    Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/TestLap/TC2/xxx.php on line 66
```

La línea 66 se refiere nada menos que a esta parte del código referente a la obstención de datos de la BD:

```
    $Result1 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Ignoro qué puede andar mal ahora, dado que lo probé en un sistema con Windows 10 y corriendo servidor local XAMPP y funcionó sin problemas, pude insertar los datos a la BD. No obstante, al probarlo en un sistema con Linux (en concreto, Ubuntu), es donde me arroja este error.

Si alguien me pudiera apoyar con este problema, se lo voy a agradecer. Saludos y buen dia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje *`mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given`* significa literalmente: *`mysqli_error () espera exactamente 1 parámetro, 0 dado`*.

Significa que tienes que pasar un parámetro a `mysqli_error()`. Dicho parámetro es la conexión, como bien explica el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php).

Para resolverlo tienes que ponerlo así:

```
$Result1 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($TC2P));
```

Donde quiera que uses `mysqli_error($tienesQuePasarLaConexionAqui)`

Si antes te funcionaba era porque no ocurrían errores. En tu nuevo entorno si no funciona es porque quizá estén ocurriendo errores y al intentar usar `mysqli_error()` sin parámetros salta esta advertencia.

Te recomiendo que siempre que tengas problemas con alguna función de PHP revises el Manual, el cual explica claramente y con ejemplos cómo funciona, qué parámetros se deben pasar, etc.

Comment: Pues al parecer funcionó. Pero yo no sabía que había que pasar la conexión de la DB por ´die(mysqli_error());´. Menciono esto porque hasta ahora no me había salido ese error. Incluso hasta llegué a pensar que la falla estaría en la versión del servidor de MySQL, pero bueno. Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @MauroMartin [revisa el enlace que pongo en la respuesta](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php). Allí te explica claramente que en el modo procedural debes pasar la conexión en parámetro a `mysqli_error()`.